# Adding repository and pluginRepository to maven project(eclipse)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, repository

I need to add

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

in pom.xml so I can run my project with `spring-boot` according to another question here, but the problem is I don't know how to do this. The only thing I found is:

> right click on pom.xml->Import->Git->Repositories from GitHub

but it's not from GitHub so it doesn't work.

Comment: All spring-boot dependencies that are released are available on maven-central and therefore you don't have to add the repositories.
Do you want to use any milestone or snapshot builds of spring-boot dependencies?

Comment: I saw that I can directly add the repository by typing the code in my question but after that another problem came up.

Comment: Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.9.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project ffff: An exception occurred while running. null: InvocationTargetException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat: Error creating bean with name 'httpPutFormContentFilter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed;